# Auditing access to a linked server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, linked-server, audit

I have a linked server with SQL Server configured with the security option "For a login not defined in the above list, connections will: Be made using the login's current security context".

What I want to do is start logging which logins are using the linked server, and preferably whether the connection succeeded or failed, and where the login came from (which database, stored procedure, etc.).

Is this possible? I can't find anything obvious.

Comment: Refer to *[How to Trace to See if a Linked Server is Being Used?](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/5044a52c-f09b-4ac2-8a85-df627e677c33/how-to-trace-to-see-if-a-linked-server-is-being-used?forum=sqldatabaseengine)*. It seems pretty straightforward. I'm going to be using trace to audit this...

Comment: That would be useful for a one-off or occasional check, but probably not so useful for creating a permanent audit log?